# $n>0$ balls into $x \ge 2$ bins. X represents the number of balls landing in bin 1, and $Y$ the number of balls landing in bin 2.

Tags: probability, random-variables, linear-regression, balls-in-bins

I'm having trouble solving this problem. I don't really know how to do it especially the last part.

We throw n>0 balls into x >= 2 bins. X represents the number of balls landing in bin1, and Y the number of balls landing in bin2.

- Calculate: E[X], E[Y], E[X|Y], Var(X), cov(X,Y)
- Calculate: L[X|Y], L[Y|X], Q[X|Y]? (where Q[X|Y] is the best quadratic estimator of Y given X, and L represents the Linear Least Square Estimate)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Ok no problem, give me few minutes, and I'll update the body!

Comment: Finding $E[X]$ and  $E[Y]$ are very easy, $E[X\mid Y]$ and $Var(X)$ are not much harder.  $cov(X,Y)$ requires a little thought but is possible.  I have no idea what  $L[X\mid Y], L[Y\mid X], Q[X\mid Y]$ represent here

Answer (score 0):

For 2 states you can easily convert this to a cointoss puzzle. For example if I toss n coins how many heads is same as how many  will land in bin1. Similarly bin2 is tails. You can add more states easily